# Does lying violate the maxim of quality?

Tags: pragmatics

Hope to find someone here to help me decide whether this is a **violation** or **opting out** of the quality maxim in the following example:
A: Did you pass the driving test?
B: No. (A knows that B passed the test)

Comment: A is violating the cooperative principle by asking a question they know the answer to. Since Grice's maxims as usually formulated deal with statements but not questions, it's hard to see which one they're transgressing, and whether it's venial or mortal.

Comment: Does B know that A knows? Does A know that B knows that A knows? :)

Comment: @jlawler I'm not sure about that. A could be testing B to see if he'll tell the truth, in which case there is no violation.

Comment: OP, does it matter that A knows that B passed the test?